# Get Item from Array with Property equal to Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch

This questions is for my LightSwitch project but I'm not sure that's renavent.  I've never done javascript or jquery before and i'm pretty sure this will have nothing to do with LightSwitch and everything to do with the latter.

The following code works perfectly setting test equal to 4 in my case:

```
myapp.BrowseTreeNodes.TreeNodes_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    var screen = contentItem.screen;
    var result = screen.MyArray.data[0];
    var test = result.Id;
}
```

What I need to do is instead of setting result to the first item in the array I need to set result to the item with a specific Id, for this example let's say 4.

Here's what i've tried:

```
var result = $.grep(screen.MyArray.data, function (e) { return e.Id === 4; })[0];
var result = screen.MyArray.data.filter(function (v) { return v.Id === 4; })[0];
var result = screen.MyArray.data.find(x => x.Id === 4)[0];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your problem may be the `===` , `===` checks for type as well, so `"4" === 4` is `false`  while `"4" == 4` is `true`, check if your id property is stored as a string or an integer...

Comment: OMG thank you, I was tearing my hair out over this.  The $.grep line worked great when I changed it to == 4.  I'll mark this as the solution if you submit it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: great!, glad i could help, i posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem may be the `===` , `===` checks for type as well, so `"4" === 4` is `false`  while `"4" == 4` is `true`, check if your id property is stored as a string or an integer...